# Pass method with argument to other class method

Tags: php

While I was trying to translate my website I came across a problem. 
I first used to translate something from an array with many keys but now I want to do it with a function.

So here is my code which obviously doesn't work:

```
class Foo extends Database {
   private $crumb = 'Hello';

   public function breadcrumb( callable $translate ) {
       return $translate($this->crumb);
       // So: $bar->translate($this->crumb);
   }
}

class Bar extends Database {
   private $translation = ['Hello'=>'Hallo']; // Array made out of words comming from a database

   public function translate($word) {
      return $this->translation[$word];
   }
}
```

On a page:

```
<?php
$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();
?>
<h1><? echo $foo->breadcrumb($bar->translate()); ?></h1> <!-- Expected result <h1>Hallo</h1> -->
```

As you can see I have the classes already extended by another class so extending `Foo` with `Bar` isn't possible. 
So my problem is how can I call a method inside another class's method? I have this problem in a couple of other classes too.

I found a few things like below but still didn't help me.

- [Passing an instance method as argument in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543143/passing-an-instance-method-as-argument-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: For clarity: You wrote: "So my problem is how can I call a method inside another class's method?"
Do I undertsand that you want to call a method in another class's METHOD? I think you mean you want to call a method in another class, right?

Comment: @ErwinMoller I guess so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php says:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

```
<?php
class Foo /* extends Database */ {
   private $crumb = 'Hello';

   public function breadcrumb( callable $translate ) {
       return $translate($this->crumb);
   }
}

class Bar /* extends Database */ {
   private $translation = ['Hello'=>'Hallo'];

   public function translate($word) {
      return $this->translation[$word];
   }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;
echo $foo->breadcrumb( [$bar, 'translate'] ); ?>
```

(you also forgot the $this-> reference for accessing the instance memeber `translation`.)