# Argument passed to function must be callable, array given

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm trying to run a method on each element inside a collection. It's an object method residing in the same class:

```
protected function doSomething()
{
    $discoveries = $this->findSomething();
    $discoveries->each([$this, 'doSomethingElse']);
}

protected function doSomethingElse($element)
{
    $element->bar();
    // And some more
}
```

If I precede the call on `Collection::each` with the check `is_callable([$this, 'doSomethingElse'])` it returns true, so apparently it is callable. The call itself however throws an exception:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::each() must
>      be callable, array given, called in ---.php on line 46

The method trying to be called can be found [here](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Collection.php#L241-L250).

I'm bypassing this by just passing a closure that itself simply calls that function, but this would definitely a much cleaner solution and I can't find out why it throws the error.

Comment: @bxN5 It's not supposed to be a function, it's supposed to be a `callable`. `is_callable` returns true, so I would assume it works when passed to a function expecting a `callable`.

Comment: please try to declare `doSomethingElse()` as `public`. IMHO I suppose that `each()` is called in the context of the `collection` class that does not have visibility on protected functions in other classes.

Comment: I suspect that `findSomething` or `doSomethingElse` is throwing an exception. In my limited experience, this error message is a red herring.

Comment: That might be the case, though in the meantime I solved it differently and can't remember the exact place where I used it, thus I'm unable to verify.

Answer (score 48):

Change the visibility of your callback method to public.

```
protected function doSomething()
{
    $discoveries = $this->findSomething();
    $discoveries->each([$this, 'doSomethingElse']);
}

public function doSomethingElse($element)
{
    $element->bar();
    // And some more
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Since PHP 7.1 you can leave your function protected. Now you can write:

```
protected function doSomething()
{
    $discoveries = $this->findSomething();
    $discoveries->each(\Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'doSomethingElse']));
}

protected function doSomethingElse($element)
{
    $element->bar();
    // And some more
}
```

[Source](https://josephsilber.com/posts/2016/07/13/closure-from-callable-in-php-7-1)

Answer (score 3):

function with callback

```
public function foo(callable $callback){ 
    $callback('something') 
}
```

named function for callback

```
public function do($something) { 
   // 
}
```

result

```
foo(function ($something) { 
        // 
})
```

or call named function

```
foo(\Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'do']))
```

or

```
foo(this->do(...))
```

Answer (score -1):

#### PHP >= 5.4

I wasn't able to reproduce your error, but my guess is that you should use `$discoveries` instead of `$this` in the callback array, like so:

```
$discoveries->each([$discoveries, 'doSomethingElse']);
```

Even though `$discoveries` and `$this` are of the same class, and therefore can access each other's protected and private methods, the type-hinting functionality may not check that the object in the callback array is the same class as the current class. However, the `is_callable()` method will check for this, which may explain why it returns true when you call it from inside the `each()` method.

#### PHP < 5.4

There is no type named `callable`, so when you use it as a type hint, it is referring to a **class** named `callable`. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543245/3461763)

Comment: I didn‘t specify the Laravel version I was using, but it requires PHP 5.6+, so the <5.4 case is a non-issue. I‘ll give the other case a try however