# How to pass a function in another function as parameter

Tags: php

```
public function xyz(){
 echo "Hello";
}

public function abc(){

}
```

is it possible or not to pass a function as a parameter in PHP; 
i want to pass xyz function as a parameter of abc function

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: ["Semi-duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/accept-function-as-parameter-in-php) - requires PHP 5.3 or higher, [Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) requre PHP 5.4 or higher.  I'd love to elaborate with a full reply, but your question was prematurely closed/duplicate.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if you can find any others, let me know and I'll add them up top

Comment: @Phil - The second added duplicate actually gives a better hint. Otherwise, if there isn't a good duplicate, shouldn't the question rather stay open? Just seems like some questions gets closed a bit too quick.

Comment: how to do that plz answer me with code

Comment: @MagnusEriksson don't just stop at the top answer. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363617/283366) has details on class methods. I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543143/passing-an-instance-method-as-argument-in-php) that might help too

Comment: @paulsm4 the oldest supported version of PHP is 5.6 so it really shouldn't be an issue. See http://php.net/supported-versions.php. And there was nothing _"premature"_ about closing this